# How to detect an object is only weakly reachable?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

Consider the following scenario:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
WeakReference<MyObject> weak = new WeakReference<>(obj);
obj = null;

if (weak.get() == null) {
    System.out.println("OK.");
} else {
    System.out.println("STILL ALIVE!!");
}
```

The `obj` instance is eligible for Garbage Collection after the `obj = null` expression.
However, `weak.get()` will still return the object because it was still alive.

Is it possible to detect when an object is eligible for GC?

Comment: Just because it is eligible for GC, doesn't mean it will get GC'd instantly. I don't believe there is a way for you to programmatically determine GC eligibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeroen. My guess is that it is not possible either. Maybe someone knows something we don't!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    WeakReference<MyObject> weak = new WeakReference<>(obj);
    obj = null;
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    if (weak.get() == null) {
        System.out.println("OK.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("STILL ALIVE!!");
    }
```

or this

```
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    ReferenceQueue q = new ReferenceQueue();
    WeakReference<MyObject> weak = new WeakReference<>(obj, q);
    obj = null;
    System.gc();
    q.remove();
    if (weak.get() == null) {
        System.out.println("OK.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("STILL ALIVE!!");
    }
```

Comment: Of course, System.gc() is just "advisory", and the GC algorithms I'm familiar with require an object to be weakly referenced for 2 cycles before it will be GCed.

Comment: And GC may or may not choose to "clean up" weak refs on a given cycle, depending on storage pressure, etc.

Comment: I understand your approach. That's reasonable. However it rellies on the fact that after 100ms the object would have been GC. However, this may not be the case when running a more complex application. Relying on sleeps may be error prone. Besides that, your program will waste 100ms everytime you want to ensure the GC did the clean-up. Do you know whether it is possible to dettect that programatically without rellying on this approach? Something like "if strong references == 0, the obj is ellegible to GC, doesn't matter whether it was GC or not."

Comment: The second option is much better. Although System.gc() does not guarantee to run the GC, it seems to work well. I don't think there is a better option. Thanks for your answer.